# PagingDataAdapter submitData slow down UI

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-paging, android-paging-3

I'm using Paging 3 to load a list of items from room database but that slow down my app and UI looks very leggy

Here a look how i am using it

```
mViewModel.messages.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        mMessagesAdapter.submitData(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, it)
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I use this adapter for my app and have not seen this problem. You might need to examine your adapter code for performance issues. A couple of potential trouble spots:

- Your `DiffUtil.ItemCallback` implementation -- how expensive is your diffing logic?
- Your `onBindViewHolder()` implementation -- are you doing a lot of complex UI here? or processor intensive work on the main thread?

Also worth inspecting: how are you loading the data from Room? Make sure that you are doing the database query on a background thread.